# Correct implementation of min

Tags: c++, min, theory

At time 0:43:15 in this [Tech-Talk about D](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlVpPstLPEc), The implementation of the min function is discussed. Concerns about "stability" and "extra shuffling (if values are equal)" when being used in some algorithm(s) is proposed as one of the reasons for the implementation shown.

Can anyone provide a real/practical use-case (or provide a more detailed explanation) where this specific implementation of min is "stable" (aka better) as opposed to its other possible implementation? Or is this just another example of alpha-geeks going a bit too far?

Recommended implementation:

```
template <class LHS, class RHS, class Return>
inline Return min(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs)
{
   return (rhs < lhs) ? rhs : lhs;
}
```

Other possible implementation:

```
template <class LHS, class RHS, class Return>
inline Return min(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs)
{
   return (lhs < rhs) ? lhs: rhs;
}
```

Proposal [N2199](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html) provides implementations that are based on the latter, please note that the proposal was not successful at this time.

Other relevant proposals relating to min/max are [N1840](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1840.pdf), [N2485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2485.pdf) and [N2551](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2551.pdf)

Comment: I don't get it. I can't see any advantage for one of the implementation you show. At some point, one of them must be chosen...

Comment: I find it highly amusing how a question of very narrow focus and limited applicability is rated extremely highly when a question of very broad focus and applicable to almost everybody gets called 'off-topic'.  I know that in programming details can be extremely important.  But this one is very narrowly important and I would never depend on the stability of min to be correct in code I wrote anyway because it's too tiny a detail to depend on anybody getting right.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I think you have misunderstood the issue, its not about something trivial, but rather an issue that has been haunting C++ for the last 10 years, but to further that, one of the world experts in the language and some people at a somewhat prestigious organisation such as Google, have made a comment, and made it sound soo normal and "matter of fact" when most in the industry would agree to the contrary, that one can't help but wonder if this is another Kepler or Galileo situation of calling the world round... most likely its all just nonsense, but why not discuss it?

Comment: @sonicoder - I think it's worth discussing.  I think it deserves a rating of about '2'.  So I think that it's ridiculously overrated as a question.  I find that my tastes in what's important and worthwhile seem quite at odds with many people here.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Sorting has always been a pet problem in CS :) Anyway I much prefer this question to the "why is i = ++i + ++i undefined ?" lot or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174972/how-does-stl-return-2-iterators-with-the-same-function. This one does make me think, it's becoming rarer and rarer this day.

Answer (score 38):

In this case, I'm pretty sure "stable" is referring to stable as it's applied in sorting -- i.e., that when/if two elements are equal, they stay sorted in the same order as they were to start with. To accomplish that, you want to return `lhs` when it's less than or equal to `rhs` -- but in C++ you (normally) want to do that using only `operator<`, without depending on having `operator<=`.

Comment: This is clear. But how come the same logic is not applied to `std::max`? Shouldn't it then return its *second* argument out of two equivalent ones? Yet, the standard explicitly states that `std::max` also returns the first argument in such cases.

Comment: @AnTstandswithRussia:  Yes, there's certainly at least room for argument that it would be better for `std::max` to return the second element in case of a tie. I'm not sure why it's specified the way it is.

Answer (score -4):

In general case there is no advantage to one implementation over the other.
If you're implementing `min` for a specific usage, it might make sense to choose one of the forms based on the data to which it will be applied to make the most of branch predictions.

If for most usage cases the expected minimum is `rhs`, choose the first implementation.
If it's `lhs`, choose the second implementation.

Comment: Branch prediction can predict falses just as usefully as trues.