# How does STL return 2 iterators with the same function?

Tags: c++

I noticed that vector.begin() will return a const iterator, or an iterator based on what is given on the left. How is something like this implemented since the arguments given to the function are the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its return-type is based on whether the vector itself is being accessed through a `const` reference (or pointer) or not.  Also, an `iterator` can be implicitly converted to a `const_iterator`, which is why something like this works: `std::vector<T> v; std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = v.begin();`.

Answer (score 5):

`begin()` and `end()` are overloaded on the const-ness of `*this`, something like:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const;

iterator end();
const_iterator end() const;
```

Answer (score 3):

They are overloaded on the const-ness of the member function:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar() { return 1; }
    int bar() const { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo a;
    const Foo b;
    assert(a.bar() == 1);
    assert(b.bar() == 2);
}
```