# Implementation of std::min

Tags: c++

The implementation of `std::min` on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and in the [original stl](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_algobase.h) looks like this:

```
return (b < a) ? b : a;
```

But I think this is slightly more readable:

```
return (a < b) ? a : b;
```

Which makes me wonder: are both implementations equivalent? Is there a particular reason why it is implemented like it is?

Comment: I don't know the rationale behind this implementation but both should result in the same output and I think it's a matter of style.

Comment: Some sort of symmetry with the implementation of `max`? I.e. stress the flip in the comparison rather then stress the flip in return values.

Comment: @BoBTFish I was just thinking the same.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174447/correct-implementation-of-min

Comment: They aren't equivalent: http://ideone.com/ej7TIA .  If `std::min` allowed two different types, they'd also differ in return type (one would be `decltype(b)`, the other `decltype(a)`).

Comment: @yakk, aren't both of them of type `const T &`?

Comment: They could both inherit from type T.

Comment: Note that The Standard guarantees that both `min` and `max` return "the first argument when the arguments are equivalent", or "a copy of the leftmost argument when several arguments are equivalent to the
smallest" for the `c++11` `initializer_list` versions. (25.4.7)

Comment: @BoBTFish, you may want to write that as an answer. It's the best answer in my opinion. Even better, put that answer in the post Nate linked to (which this post is a duplicate of).

Comment: I think it might be a useful footnote inside another answer, but it doesn't really add any understanding.

Comment: @Shahbaz I said "if `std::min` allowed two different types".  It doesn't allow two different types.  @BobTFish your answer points out why the second one wouldn't be a legal `std::min`.

Comment: @Yakk Won't the result of a `a?b:c` always be some type compatible with both `b` and `c`? I.e. the same as `a?c:b`. In fact in `c++11` this is called [`common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type).

Comment: @BobTFish bah, I read a bad source that claimed the type of `a?b:c` was `b`.

Answer (score 6):

The two different implementations would determine whether you choose the first or the second object as minimum if they are equal, which may make a difference for objects, if not for primitive types.

This, coupled with implementation of some other algorithms could have a larger impact. For example, if a sort algorithm uses `min(a[i], a[j])` where `i < j` and `a[i]` and `a[j]` have the same value, the first implementation would result in no swap between the elements while the second does, making the sort unstable.

---

Note: As [BoBTFish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088900/implementation-of-stdmin/17089637#comment24719041_17088900) mentioned, the C++11 standard guarantees that both min and max return the left most minimum:

> 25.4.7:
>
> 3 *Remarks:* Returns the first argument when the arguments are equivalent
>
> 6 *Remarks:* Returns a copy of the leftmost argument when several arguments are equivalent to the smallest

Comment: The two implemntations are NOT the same, see the post below by @ChrisCM -- ( b < a) != (a > b)

Comment: @BenBrammer, yes that's why I removed the first part of my answer (4 minutes before your comment).

Comment: @Shabaz, my apologies, I was slow to catch up.  My bad.

Comment: @Shabaz: downvote removed, but you don't get my upvote, because you essentially hijacked my answer for rep, after initially getting it completely wrong :P

Comment: @ChrisCM, actually I hijacked it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4174519/912144

Comment: @ChrisCM, but anyway, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088900/implementation-of-stdmin/17088983#comment24719041_17088900) is the final answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

The implementations are not the same.  What will happen in either implementation if a and b are equal?  One will return a reference to a one will return a reference to b.  The values of course are identical.  But consider a struct in which the compare function only cared about one value, but some other values were different.  This could have dramatic implications on sorting functions attempting to guarantee a stable sort.

Ultimately it's a style choice, in the event of equality should we return the first or second parameter?  However, now that this style choice has been made, that it remains the same is very important, this is why things like standards definitions exist!

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Search for "25.4.7" regarding maximum and minimum.

Comment: But how to correct it then?

Comment: Don't mess with the implementation of min....

Comment: @thefourtheye, what's there to correct?! Who said anything about anything being wrong?

Comment: As a more accurate side note, the standard already says that in case of equality the left is returned. So it's not a style choice in the implementation (it may very well have been a style choice in the standard, though the duplicate question's top answer and *Shahbaz*'s answer say it isn't).

Comment: Good point, though my post doesn't mention at what point or in what document the style choice was made...

Comment: I'm gonna leave my answer up for the link to the C++ standards doc, but you should accept Ben's answer, with Shahbaz's edits.

Comment: @ChrisCM Meh, that is rather *Shahbaz*'s answer, since the first "*Ben*-part" is rather rubbish.

Answer (score -2):

-- INCORRECT ANSWER -- SEE COMMENTS -- bb

FWIW, it hasn't been my observation that STL was written to be especially easy to read, necessarily, but it's beautifully simple; in this case, the only other possible way to get the same result would be

```
return (a <= b) ? a : b;
```

which would be one more character, and, IMHO, actually not as easy to read.  Additionally, see @Shahbaz 's commentary above on sort stability--operations like min have a well-defined behavior for inclusivity and exclusivity.

TL;DR because "Less than" is not the same as "Less than or equal to"

See comments below--this answer would be correct as a macro in C but actually is incorrect in C++ for reasons explained in the comments below.  I'm marking this as incorrect but leaving it up because the comments are useful and important to understand.  I apologize if I confused the issue for anyone.

Comment: Also, the standard library prefers to use `<` and `==` and not `<=`, probably to make it simpler to override operators.

Comment: *"FWIW"* - Not much at all. *"because "Less than" is not the same as "Less than or equal to""* - In fact *"less than or equal to"* isn't even the same as *"less than"* **or** *"equal to"*. That's the reason why your proposed *"other possible way"* isn't even possible, since all the standard library's ordering functionality relies on a strict weak ordering. `<=` isn't just one more character, it's a completely different operator and *totally unrelated* to `<` or `==`.

Comment: @Yakk Not only to make it simpler, but to *work at all* in case of operator overloading, since `<=` has absolutely nothing to do with `< || ==`.

Comment: @ChristianRau Had the standard used `<=`, it would have "worked".  It wouldn't mean the same as `< || ==`, but I don't see how that is relevant.  The pattern that the STL and then the standard library only uses `<` and `==` is what makes `min` be defined in terms of `<`.  Had the STL and standard library used `<=`, then `min` would be defined in terms of `<=`: the pattern of using `<` is so that users would need to define fewer operators.  Further, note that equivalence has nothing to do with `==` with regards to `std::min` -- equivalence is `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`, which is unrelated to `a == b`.

Comment: @Yakk Well, yeah, if the standard had used `<=` *everywhere*, then it would also be appropriate in `std::min`, but it didn't. *"The pattern that the STL and then the standard library only uses < and == is what makes min be defined in terms of <"* - That's what I'm saying. *"Further, note that equivalence has nothing to do with == with regards to std::min"* - Well, nobody said that anyway, rather on the contrary.

Comment: Also, historically(late 80s early 90s) < is a slightly faster operation than <= for CPUs to compute, particularly for integers(as is most common) and this is when a lot of C idioms, standards and such were coming about, and can(along with the above arguments) explain why a simple < is so widely used, and has such prominence in the standard now.

Comment: @Shahbaz What was the reason for not adding that standard quote to your own answer, but to a completely different answer?

Comment: @ChristianRau, Ben originally wrote that in a comment. I believe he deserves the upvotes related to that quote. I didn't want to rob him of his reward.

Comment: @Shahbaz Can't find it, I thought that comment was from *BoBTFish* originally.

Comment: @ChristianRau, ah yeah. Two `B`s got me confused. I'll move it to my answer then since Bob didn't write an answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau makes some important clarifications.  The distinction that he points out is a crucial distinction between thinking in C and thinking in C++.